# I cant get a response from a POST request with an array in the body, Using NodeJS / Axios and Postman

Tags: node.js, axios, postman

This is a course quiz and this is the most basic information I need in order to create a React app. But while the endpoint URL is correct, the page "/products" returns a "400" error when I try to request the product list. The instructions I'm given are:

Obtain a list of products with

- Route: /products
- Body: Array
- method: POST

```js
{
  "product-codes": [
    "98798729",
    "84876871",
    "29879879",
  ]
}
```

**My index.js**

```js
...

app.post(`/products`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${apiURL}/products`);
    // console.log(response.data);
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

**in Postman**
I use http://localhost:4000/products
and pass a Body / Raw /JSON:

```js
{
  "product-codes": [
    "98798729",
    "84876871",
    "29879879",
  ]
}
```

But I can't get in! I am not seeing something obvious because this is the entry point to a very long and complex quiz. Thanks

Comment: you are not passing array in the body of request 
    const response = await axios.post(`${apiURL}/products`, data);

Comment: ` const response = await axios.post(`${apiURL}/products`);` It is a post request and you are not passing any body to it. check the post version of axios, you need to pass the body to receive it.

Comment: Thanks @zabusa  but I thought I was passing the body using Postman do I have to send it via axios AND Postman to get a response?

Comment: and thanks also @ApoorvaChikara. I am using Postman.

Comment: Yes, if you won't pass body to axios nothing will be returned.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara do you mean like this:
app.post(`/products`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${apiURL}/products`,
      (body = {
        product_skus: [
          "14003907",
          "14003884",
          "14003902",
          "14003894",
          "14003883",
          "14003870",
        ],
      })
    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see from the code is a recursive long call.

```
app.post(`/products`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${apiURL}/products`); // calling the same end point 
    // console.log(response.data);
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

You should do something like this:

```
app.post(`/products`, async (req, res) => {
    // do your logic
    // when you pass body from postman on this endpoint
   // you will receive the body here and save it to DB
   // or do the manipulation and then send back the response
    res.status(200).json(req.body.data);
});
```

I highly recommend you to first follow through some tutorials to understand how API works and how to [create simple API](https://www.codementor.io/@olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd) using `Node.js`.

Comment: thank you Apporva. You helped me get over the line. Yes, I will do the logic to manipulate the product IDs, but I just wanted to get it working first so that I can move on. I had "axios.get( ... )" instead of axios.post(...)" in the previous step. Now it works and I can move one ... until the next problem arises. I will take your advice and continue reviewing tutorials.